# Why is my BIOS power-on password not resetting even though my CMOS battery has been out for over an hour?

Tags: motherboard, bios, passwords, battery

I have an old HP xw8400 workstation.  I didn't remember the power-on password I had set for it.  So I unplugged the computer, took out the CMOS battery, and left it out for over an hour.  But the system still asks for the power-on password.

I even tried rebooting without the CMOS battery altogether.  There was no difference.  I was still asked for the power-on password.

I have read that usually it is enough to take out the battery for 10 to 15 minutes.  Why is this method not working in my case?  (Yes, I am certain I am taking out the CMOS battery.  It is flat, round, lies between the two graphics cards, at a location that corresponds to all the pictures I have checked on the Internet.)

Can someone please suggest what I should do?

**EDIT**

This is a typical example of the advice I have been following:

http://www.ehow.com/how_7249995_reset-password-removing-cmos-battery.html

Comment: On some newer computers it stores the password in non-volatile memory. Not sure if this computer would be old/new enough to do/not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly, you are likely screwed.

The xw8400 comes with a [TPM (Trusted Platform Module)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), the TPM stores things like the BIOS password. No amount of removing the battery or doing motherboard jumpers will unlock the BIOS password screen.

How do I know this? I have a nw8440 that has a TPM too that I set the BIOS password on 6 years ago that I still have not been able to unlock.

Comment: I fear you may be right.  I have tried everything I can think of for the last six hours or so.  Nothing will reset the password.  In fact, even before the password screen comes up, I know the BIOS has not been reset because the custom name I had given to my workstation is displayed on the very first screen after powering on.

Answer (score 3):

The motherboard has a specific reset password jumper.

[HP xw8400 Service and Technical Reference Guide](http://h50146.www5.hp.com/lib/doc/manual/workstation/xw8400/364898-001.pdf#page=190) page 180 for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that the battery in some systems only serves to power the real time clock and that most of the CMOS bits are NVRAM, i.e. flash.

Look for a reset jumper on the motherboard.

You could try removing the hard drive and rebooting the system.  I had an old Packard Bell that reset the BIOS password when I did that.

Comment: I just tried removing the hard disks.  It didn't work.  The password screen comes anyway.  I've been trying hard to find a reset jumper, but I can't find it.  There is nothing like it anywhere near the CMOS battery (which is where many web pages said I should look).

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever tried hitting the BIOS reset button on your main board. In many of the HP machine there will be a button for resetting the BIOS password. press down that button for 3 or 5 seconds will reset the BIOS. you can refer [this](http://h50146.www5.hp.com/lib/doc/manual/workstation/xw8400/364898-001.pdf) service manual(page # 56) for doing so.

In some of the machine there will be a reset jumper, while doing reset using jumper you should have to follow certain steps

1.Remove jumper only after the A/C power is disconnected.

2.Do not replace the jumper until you powered on the PC with it removed

3.Again shut down, remove the A/C power and replace the jumper back to its position.